# Trying to style UIButton, getting errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, calayer, uicolor

I am attempting to make my UIButtons more stylish and appealing to the eye, but when I try to use some code that i have found, it keeps telling me, Expected declaration and does not want to work.

```
CAGradientLayer *btnGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer]
btnGradient.frame = btn.bounds
btnGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0f / 255.0f green:102.0f / 255.0f blue:102.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:51.0f / 255.0f green:51.0f / 255.0f blue:51.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
nil]
[btn.layer insertSublayer:btnGradient atIndex:0]

CALayer *btnLayer = [btn layer]
[btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES]
[btnLayer setCornerRadius:5.0f]
```

I fixed the issue it was having, i changed the code to swift, but now when I implement the gradient background for the UIButton, it takes the rounded corners off and i can not figure out why. Here is my code now...

```
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    gradient.colors = [
        UIColor.grayColor().CGColor,
        UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
    ]
    gradient.locations = [0 , 1.0]

    /* make it horizontal */
    gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1)

    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
```

Comment: This is Objective-C code. You can't use this in a Swift file, it won't understand the language, that's why you get "Expected declaration".

Comment: You are missing a lot of semicolons.

Comment: Like basically all the semicolons.

Answer (score 3):

The `Expected Declaration` error is exclusively a Swift error. The code you have here is Objective-C, as denoted by the square bracket ('[' and ']') notation, as well as * (pointers).

You have two options:

1. Convert the file to Objective-C. If you don't know Objective-C, this is going to take more time than it's going to save.
2. Convert the code to Swift. Some of the classes don't exist in Swift, but most of the method calls are the same, except with [object method] changed to object.method().